# Solr full-text search

Tags: php, solr, solarium

I have these entries in the DB:

```
1:{
  first_name:"david",
  last_name:"cohen"
}

2:{
  first_name:"david king",
  last_name:"cohen"
}
```

The search logic that is required is a complete-word match:

searching for "david ki" - will return null

searching for "david king" - will return  2

searching for "david cohen" - will return both 1 + 2

In MySQL my query looks like that:

```
WHERE first_name REGEXP '[[:<:]]{$first_name}[[:>:]]' AND last_name REGEXP '[[:<:]]{$last_name}[[:>:]]'
```

I have tried building the query like this:

```
if ( $search_params ) {
    foreach ( $search_params as $search_param_key => $search_params_value ) {
        if ( $search_params_value ) {
            $search_query_fields[] = "{$search_param_key}:\"{$search_params_value}\"";
        }
    }

    $query_string = implode( ' AND ', $search_query_fields );

    $query->setQuery( $query_string );
}
```

How can I imitate the same MySQL query on SOLR ?

Comment: why david king" - will return 2 should return 2 results?...

Comment: Would `defType=edismax&q=david cohen&qf=first_name last_name&mm=100%` work? i.e. require all terms in the query to match in `first_name` or `last_name`.

Comment: @MatsLindh: It doesn't work this is the query as you suggested right ? :{
      "mm":"100%",
      "defType":"edismax",
      "q.alt":"david cohen",
      "qf":"first_name last_name",
      "stopwords":"true",
      "_":"1614858850788"}}

Comment: @Abhijit Bashetti: shold return object #2

Comment: I didn't mention `q.alt` - just `q` (but that might not matter), but does it return anything? What is the type of the `first_name` and `last_name` fields?

Comment: returns nothing both are "string" using  q gives the same results